# Why is my UISearchBar not updating the results?

Tags: swift

I have a problem with the implementation of my ***UISearchBar***. It is not updating the results in my tableView and I don´t know why it is not working. [Here](https://pastebin.com/87y0NH7w) is the full source code of my class.

---

```
var searchBar = UISearchBar()

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchBar) {
        searchBarText = searchController.text?.lowercased()
        searchBarScope = searchController.selectedScopeButtonIndex
        showList()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        if (navigationItem.title != nil) {
            self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [String(format: "gesamte %@", ci("project_s")),  String(format: "in %@", navigationItem.title!)]
        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        updateSearchResults(for: searchBar)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        navigationItem.title = navigationItem.title ?? ci("plan_p")

        guard let projectId = GlobalState.selectedProjectId, let byProject : Results<Structure> = self.by(projectId: projectId) else {
            return
        }

        //search bar
        tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar


        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.searchBar.delegate = self

        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

What am I missing? I am thankful for any input from you guys!

Comment: Use a `UISearchController` initialized with a `search results controller` instead.

Comment: Is it not possible with UISearchBar in my case or why do you recommend using a UISearchController instead? I did it with a ***UISearchController*** and it worked but it pushed my NavigationBar outside of the picture because of its animation. Thats why I wanted to use a ***UISearchBar***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set tableView delegate and dataSource in viewDidLoad like:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
table.dataSource = self;
```

i think you are missing above.